# Why using list() inside a loop return memory error in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, range

I got the following piece of code:

```
var = []
for i in range(0,len(code_list)-11):
        
        sorted_list = sorted(code_list[i:i+10]) 
        minmax_list = list(range(min(sorted_list), max(sorted_list)+1))
        
        if (sorted_list == minmax_list):
            var = var+lista_ordenada
```

When the `code_list` is so large a memory error return.
However, when replacing for the following:

```
var = []
for i in range(0,len(code_list)-11):
        
        sorted_list = sorted(code_list[i:i+10]) 
        minmax_list = np.arange(min(sorted_list), max(sorted_list)+1, 1).tolist()
        
        if (sorted_list == minmax_list):
            var = var+lista_ordenada
```

The routine ends successfully. Does anyone know the reason?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

`tolist()` will convert all the data to python standard library types. It also knows it is a numpy array and has access to highly optimized backing array.

`list` just uses an iterator to add all the elements so is much slower and more memory intensive.

Comment: Why is it more memory intensive? I think you are on to something with the use of `numpy` numeric types versus built-ins.

Comment: Rather than me write it out there is a great explanation with visuals here. https://www.python-course.eu/numpy.php. Basically np.array = 96 + n * 8 Bytes, list = 64 + 8 len(lst) + len(lst) 28. Where n and lst are the numbers in the list. The more numbers you have the better you are off with an array.

Comment: That doesn't explain why `list(some_array)` requires more memory than `some_array.tolist()`, that just explains why `some_list` requires more memory than `some_array`

Comment: "`list` just uses an iterator to add all the elements" this seems to imply that list cannot know the length it will need to be up front, but it can certainly check `len(...)` before it starts and preallocate if the length is available (which it is for `range(...)`).

Comment: @ArthurTacca yes, indeed, and in CPython, I believe `iter(arg_to_list).__length_hint__()` is used

Comment: Not sure what your getting at ? Smallest python object is 16 bytes. Numpy single precision 4 bytes. If you have `some_array` which is n bytes, list will be n bytes. Numpy just gives the smallest possible value

Comment: @GhandiFloss that doesn't address the question at all. In both cases, a list is created. So why is creating a numpy.ndarray *first* and then a list taking less memory (presumably) Also: "If you have some_array which is n bytes, list will be n bytes" **absolutely incorrect**. This list will be, roughly, `96 + n *size_of_objects_in_list` still. It doesn't matter if it was creatd from a numpy array, it's still a list

Comment: As stated, because it will create the smallest possible allocation rather than a list having a minimum of 16 bytes. I think you are overthinking things.

Comment: @GhandiFloss no, you are simply not addressing anything I'm saying. You realize, the list will still contain *python objects*, so each object in the resulting list will require at least 16 bytes. It *doesn't matter that the list was created from an array*.

Comment: "it will create the smallest possible allocation" What is the "it" in this? Do you mean the numpy array, or the list that is created from the numpy array by `to_list()`?